# Can HTTP reverse proxies enable HTTP Keep-Alive on the client side and on the server side correlated?

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I mean that all messages sent from a given ClientA<->RP tcp session will be forwaded to the same RP<->Server tcp session. (And that no other client tcp connection would be able to reuse the same RP<->Server tcp connection)

Looking at  mod_proxy I see I can set the HTTP Keep-Alive on the client side, and separately on the server side, but I don't see the option to join them...

It could be useful in situations in which you need to support NTLM thought reverse proxies, isn't it?

Comment: If you want to proxy protocols other than HTTP and achieve the behavior you're after, it seems like a TCP proxy, rather than HTTP proxy, might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems squid defined the concept of "Connection Pinning" to solve this. http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ConnPin

Comment: What is it?....